# Find Big O involving a sum of logs

Tags: math, big-o, recurrence, logarithm

I have a recurrence question, which breaks down to a summation of logs, but I am unable to solve it. Any help is appreciated.
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + nlog(n)
T(1) = 1

I drew the recurrence tree, and I know it has a depth of log(n).
I got that O(n) = nlog(n) + nlog(n/2) + nlog(n/4) + ... + n
this has log(n) terms
Taking the n out, this gives the following summation problem:
n * summation i = 0 to log(n) of log(n/2^i)

I am unsure how to solve this summation

EDIT: all bases for the logs are 2

Comment: It might be relevant that e.g. `log(n/4) = log(n) - log(4)`

Comment: Use John's hint; it will give you `T(n) ~ O(n log^2 n)`

Comment: Can you show how you got it? because i am getting O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

You already said it:

> n * summation i = 0 to log(n) of log(n/2^i)

simplify `log(n/2^i) = log(n) - i*log(2)` and you get
`n * log(n) * log(n) - log(2) * sum over i from 0 to log(n)`
where `log(2) = 1` and the sum is something like `log^2(n)/2`.
So you get `T(n) = O(n*log^2(n))`.

Also have a look at [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form) to solve such recurrence equations. This is a special case and it give you the same result.